# Angular 8: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: http, post, upload

The following code should upload a file to an HTTP server.

```js
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;

    let file: File = fileList[0];
    let body: FormData = new FormData();
    let headers = new Headers();
    // No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    console.log ('name='+file.name+ ' size='+file.size);
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    body.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);

    this.http.post(`${'http://localhost:8000'}`, body, options).subscribe (data => {console.log ('response',data);});
```

Upon running the post I got the error in the title.

Can you please tell what is wrong in my code ?

I have package.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

What is 3000 ? Is it the port of the HTTP server ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: Are you working on local system?

Comment: Yes. client (chrome) and server are running on the same PC.

Answer (score 2):

It seems because of the CORS ORIGIN issue. You need to install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) extension then it will work fine on your local system. Then you need to enable it and run your code. On live, your code is work as per your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

This happens becuase your front and back have not the same URL and port, it's a cross-domain request.

You have to add a proxy config, please check this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my project, the file webpack.config.js does not contain "devServer" at all. I added it at the end. After npm start, the server is getting a message but without the body and with another headers. Can you please help ?

Comment: @ZviVered could you please accept the my response and ask a new question with the more details?